# Meaning of 'nuclear surface vibrations'?

Tags: nuclear-physics, terminology

Would like to know the meaning of [nuclear surface vibrations](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=nuclear+surface+vibrations) as mentioned by Bohr in his paper titled 'The coupling of nuclear surface vibrations to the motion of individual nucleons'. The paper talks about the presence of a centrifugal force that the nucleons experience which causes them to hit the wall of the nucleus causing it to deform. I do not understand where does this centrifugal force arise from and what sort of 'nucear surface vibrations' or oscillations is the nucleus undergoing for this model.

Comment: Are you aware of the [liquid](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/nuclear/liqdrop.html) [drop](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2011/ph241/chen1/) model of the nucleus?